# Как вывести изображение в backend-списке OctoberCMS?

Tags: html, twig, yaml

Имеется поле в таблице `logo`, которое содержит абсолютный путь к изображению. Мне нужно при отображении в админке в виде списка вывести лого как изображение `<image ...>` 
Делал по документации http://octobercms.com/docs/backend/lists#column-partial.

Создал шаблон:

```
<img width="64" height="auto" src="{{ value }}">
```

Подключил для поля в columns.yaml

```
logo:
    type: partial
    path: ~/plugins/...../_logo_column.twig
```

В итоге, Twig не обрабатывает этот шаблон, все выводится в html как есть (с фигурными скобками `{{ value }}` ). Что я делаю не так?

Answer (score 1):

Решено: в шаблонах backend twig не работает, есть только выполнение php

Answer (score 0):

вот рабочий пример:

```
<?php if($record->project_poster){ ?>
    <img src="<?= $value->getThumb(40,40, 'crop') ?>">

<?php } ?>
```